# How to get facebook notification webhooks in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, webhooks

I m trying to set up facebook notification/message webhooks, for which i have

- created the app,
- set up callback URL and verified it as well.
- But how do i capture the webhook response and save it.

Per say i tried the below code on my .php file :

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        // fetch RAW input
        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    
        // decode json
        $object = json_decode($json);
    
        // dump to file so you can see
        file_put_contents('callback.test.txt', print_r($object, true));
    }
?>
```

As i test a sample notification, i don't see any file in my server saved.

**Observations:**

As I comment out the `"if"` condition which checks `"REQUEST_METHOD"` and tried sending a test, i see a file saved in my server but an empty one.

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong, or is there any wrong on how to get webhook data from FB notifications.?

The Facebook documentation for the same : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks

The sample tests from facebook i been trying, to receive webhook triggers.

[image: sample image]

The sample json i m sending on click for test

[image: sample json]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `As I comment out the "if" condition which checks "REQUEST_METHOD" and tried sending a test, i see a file saved in my server`...this suggests the incoming request might be a GET rather than a POST. What do the Facebook docs say the request will be? Link us to the relevant documentation if you're unsure how to interpret it. Have you tried any other debugging? e.g. check if there are some parameters in $_GET, perhaps? Again, what led you to decide to try and decode the data as JSON?

Comment: @ADyson, Hi, i tried the GET as well, i still dont see any data getting saved in server as a file. and i have added the docs link from FB as well in the query. pls check

Comment: `I tried the GET as well`...what exactly did you write in your code for that? Please update us with that attempt

Comment: And what type(s) of webhooks are you trying to receive? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks#verification-requests shows that verification requests will indeed be GET requests, and shows you what fields to expect in `$_GET` (but for testing, you can always just write `file_put_contents('callback.test.txt', print_r($_GET, true));`)

Comment: However, event notifications, as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks#event-notifications, will be POST requests containing JSON. From what you said earlier, you're _probably_ receiving a GET, but please confirm which type of webhook you want to interact with, and do some more testing / show us your latest code. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson, I have attached the image where i m trying to send sample test events so that my webhook can trigger and save the same. 

the code in my webhook is mentioned in the question that starts with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Comment: What happens if you just do this one without any if-condition:

`$raw =  file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw .= PHP_EOL.'Method.'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
file_put_contents('callback.test.txt',$raw);`

?

Comment: @ADyson i replaced your code, no file is getting inserted in the sever. But just to test if i open the webhook link directly, i get the file with content as `Method.GET`, which shows no issue on file creation or saving.

Comment: `the code in my webhook is mentioned in the question that starts with $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].`...yes I know that, but then you said `i tried the GET as well, i still dont see any data getting saved`, which sounded like you tried having code to read GET data. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: `no file is getting inserted in the sever`...are you sure no errors are occuring which prevent the file being written? Do you have PHP error logging enabled? Does it show anything in the PHP error log file? Also did you remove the `if` condition before testing with `file_put_contents('callback.test.txt', print_r($_GET, true));`? Because obviously if the request is a GET, then as you observed before, `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {` would prevent it from proceeding.

Comment: @ADyson i did tried GET method as well (just replaced `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {` to `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {` ) this time, file is being created and saved but no data init... :(

Comment: From reading the documentation again, it says anytime you send a webhook request for the first time it will send a verification GET request with the stated parameters, and then it will expect you to return one of those parameters as the response. Thereafter it will, presumably, send the POST request as normal. So I'd guess what's happening is you're seeing the GET request, because you haven't yet returned a verifiable response to it.

Comment: `but no data init`....that is really very strange. Again, check for PHP errors in your logs.

Comment: @ADyson, i have done the verification process, where i have to get and send back a token that i receive from fb for verifying the link. my webhook link is verified, and even checked the error_log as well, unfortunately no errors...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254076/discussion-between-tech-stack-by-antra-and-adyson).

Comment: `i have done the verification process`...then why is it still sending you a GET? Are you sure you're testing it correctly? It's not really clear what exactly those screenshots you sent are of

Comment: @ADyson, i have done the verification process, where i have to get and send back a token that i receive from fb for verifying the link. my webhook link is verified, and even checked the error_log as well, unfortunately no errors...
I just have one small question, is this the proper way to receive data from this trigger `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');`

as per the docs they have given how to get the same in node.js (as per docs)

Comment: Yes that would be the correct way. But there won't be any JSON data in the request body because - as your results are showing us - the request you're testing with is a GET which does not have a body. Either you did not do the verification properly or you are not testing correctly, is my suspicion

Comment: And the actual webhook URL you specified does not perhaps (inadvertently) perform a redirect first? People often run into this kind of issue when f.e. specifying a URL like `.../somefolder`, which the server then first of all responds to with a redirect to `.../somefolder/`